# How to specify custom compiler flags for Visual Studio Compiler

Tags: c++, gcc, compiler-flags

With the GCC you can use `-D<custom flag>` to pass for example a value to a macro that you defined in your code. But I can't find any information on how to do this for the VSC. Does anybody know?

So an example for the GCC case would like like this:

`g++ -DMYFLAG=1 program.cpp`

Answer (score 1):

> But I can't find any information on how to do this for the VSC.

I find that hard to believe. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hhzbb5c8.aspx was the first result I got when googling "visual studio macro command line". Failing that, <kbd>F1</kbd> or searching MSDN would still get you the same answer.

> /D (Preprocessor Definitions)
>
> Defines a preprocessing symbol for a source file.
>
> Syntax
>
> ```
> /Dname[= | # [{string | number}] ]
> ```

Comment: I am not using Visual Studio environment and you have to know what to search for. Thanks.

Comment: So `cl.exe /?` was not the first thing you tried? And no, you don't have to know what to search for. "visual studio command line options", "visual studio compiler switches", any combination of those would've gotten you the answer. Don't be so lazy.

Comment: well, I searched for "visual studio custom compiler flags" and varianst of that. Of course you need to know what to search for. Don't be so ignorant.