# Passing custom compiler flags to bsds gcc

Tags: c, gcc

So, depending on how I decide to compile a program, I want to be able to execute a set of functions. This could normally be done with just a few variables and comparisons, but since I will be distributing it to systems that only have the ELF, it needs to be known at compile time what to run. Is it possible to pass in a custom gcc flag, say `-flagset` that makes it then set a MACRO in my code if that flag is set? I seen [How to specify custom compiler flags for Visual Studio Compiler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33314125/how-to-specify-custom-compiler-flags-for-visual-studio-compiler) but that is a bit vague and not appropriate for my needs

Comment: "_but that is a bit vague and not appropriate for my needs_": How is that vague and why does it not meet your requirements? It is not clear to me what you are trying to do. Can you give a more concrete example?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [gcc manual](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Preprocessor-Options.html):

> **3.13 Options Controlling the Preprocessor**
>
> -D name
> Predefine name as a macro, with definition 1.
>
> -D name=definition
> The contents of definition are tokenized and processed as if they appeared during translation phase three in a ‘#define’ directive.

That is, you can set any macro value via the `-D` option and that will be seen by the code. Example:

`gcc -DSOME_FLAG test.c`

Then in the code it can be checked as such:

```
#ifdef SOME_FLAG
    /* do code for SOME_FLAG enabled case */
#endif
```